# Can it be dangerous to curl without any option an HTTP address?

Tags: websites, curl

I wanted to know my external IP address from the command line. I found this answer on Ask Ubuntu: [Command for determining my public IP?](https://askubuntu.com/a/95911/640314) which suggests to use

```
curl -s https://checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

But the address https://checkip.dyndns.org is detected as malicious on several forums.

Was my `curl` command dangerous for my system in this case?
Also in a more general way: is a `curl` without option (and with a `sed`) dangerous? By dangerous, it can mean anything else than just printing my IP address, executing malware etc.

Comment: The URL is run by Oracle. I'm not sure why it would be listed as malicious.

Comment: @schroeder I did not know it was run by Oracle. What command/website did you use to get the info?

Comment: I know the company and I just looked at the sites footer to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

If the site was designed to exploit a vulnerability in `curl` or `sed`, then yes, it would be dangerous.

But the likelihood of that being a threat would depend on curl vulnerabilities and the site being so designed. It is unlikely that a site run by a Fortune 500 company would be so uniquely and narrowly programmed.